# What is the grammatical role of "hopeful" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> Film-making hopefuls still use shorts as calling cards.

why "hopeful" has "s"? What is its grammatical role?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: It's a [noun](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hopeful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the plural form of this meaning of "hopeful," a noun: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hopeful_2 , meaning "People who hope to succeed in film-making."